# Count the number of leap years between two years and their average using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How could you count the number of leap years and calculate their average using the following python script?

```
start = int(input("Enter start year: "))
end = int(input("Enter end year: "))

if start <= end:
    leap_years = [str(x + start) for x in range(end-start) if x % 4 == 0 and x % 100 != 0]
    leap_years[-1] += "."
    print(f"Here is a list of leap years between {start} and {end}:\n{(', '.join(leap_years))}")

from statistics import mean
leap_years = [start + x for x in range(end-start) if x % 4 == 0 and x % 100 != 0]
avg_leap_year = mean(leap_years)

print(len(leap_years))
print(avg_leap_year)
```

Please let me know if this script could be improved to be less redundant.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

```
from statistics import mean
leap_years = [start + x for x in range(end-start) if x % 4 == 0 and x % 100 != 0]
avg_leap_year = mean(leap_years)
```

Comment: Thank you. I included your solution to the original question. Please let me know if the script could be less redundant to remove unnecessary script.